# My relative import isn't working

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to import a module from a parent directory but I keep getting an import error.

my directory:

```
spider1_2/
    spider2.py
    __init__.py
    gui/
        __init__.py
        main.py
```

i'm trying to import spider2.py from main.py with the following.

```
from .. import spider2
```

but I get this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
     from .. import spider2
 ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Answer (score 0):

The **dot-dot** notation refers to the parent *package*, not the parent directory.  If you want to import from the directory above, you need to have that name in your python library path.

Comment: Don't the __Init__.py files make it a package?

Comment: That makes spider2 a package, not the parent directory.  Since the others have given you better detail on this problem, I'll bow out of the discussion at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting has to do with how you're running `main.py`. If you're using `python main.py` from the `gui` folder or even `python spider1_2/gui.main.py` from the top level, Python doesn't realize that the file's location is inside a package and that `main` is really `spider1_2.gui.main`. This is why it says the relative import is in a "non-package" module.

Your code will work properly if you run your `main` module from the top level folder (above `spider1_2`) with `python -m spider1_2.gui.main`.

Often you'll want to put your main script at the top level of your project, rather than deep in a package. The actual script can be very basic, just a few lines importing the real logic (from deep in the package perhaps) and calling it.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specified the version of Python you're using.

In Python 3 you don't need to use an **init**.py file.

Try `import ..spider2`

Comment: `import ..spider2` will never work in any version of Python. You must use `from ..whatever import whatever` syntax if you're doing relative imports.